# wexpect not recognizing command 'ssh'

Tags: python, windows, expect

I have downloaded wexpect.py from https://gist.github.com/anthonyeden/8488763. I saved this as wexpect.py. 
This modules imported

```
import wexpect.py
child = wexpect.spawn('ssh.exe %s@%s' % ('server1','a.b.c.d'))
```

I get the following error

```
>>> child = wexpect.spawn('ssh.exe %s@%s' % ('server1','a.b.c.d'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "wexpect.py", line 279, in spawn
return spawn_windows(command, args, timeout, maxread,
search  windowsize,    logfile, cwd, env)
File "wexpect.py", line 1653, in __init__
self._spawn (command, args)
File "wexpect.py", line 1698, in _spawn
raise ExceptionPexpect ('The command was not found or was not    
executable: %s.' % self.command)
ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: 
ssh.exe server1@a.b.c.d.
```

I am able to execute in the shell prompt. ssh.exe has been added to the PATH after installing cygwin

```
ssh server1@a.b.c.d
```

I have also set PYTHONPATH in the environmental variables (user & system) to include c:\cygwin64\bin

How is this to be done?

All help will be appreciated

Regards
Ganesh

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ***ssh*** instead of ***ssh.exe*** ?

Comment: In another stackoverflow question the suggestion was to use ssh.exe. Anyway tried both. Neither work.

Comment: Does ***sys.path*** return ***c:\cygwin64\bin*** as well?

Comment: Yes. Typing PATH in c:> does show c:\cygwin64 & c:\cygwin64\bin

Answer (score -1):

**Brief:**

Give the executable's arguments separetly:

```
import wexpect.py
child = wexpect.spawn('ssh.exe', ['%s@%s', '%', "('server1','a.b.c.d')"])
```

---

**Detail:**

Here is the header of spawn from [wexpect](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/blob/master/wexpect.py):

```
def spawn(command, args=[], timeout=30, maxread=2000, searchwindowsize=None, logfile=None, cwd=None, env=None,
          codepage=None):
```

This method waits for the executable and the arguments separately.